# Whitenoise and/or static files causing Server Error (500)

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am able to deploy my app (via Django) to Heroku when DEBUG = True but when DEBUG = False I get a Server Error. I think it has to do with how I've set up my static files. When I comment out "STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'" I don't get an error message but the site is completely unformatted. Here's the relevant settings.py code:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...    
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
...
]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
```

I've added my static folder in all sorts of locations (same folder as settings.py, in the root folder, etc) to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: run `python manage.py collectstatic` & try again, & also include what is the error exactly not 500, set DEBUG=False & try `python manage.py runserver`, & check the stack trace

Comment: As a general rule, you should avoid using the django runserver and staticfiles in production.  You’re only supposed to be using them for development purposes.

Comment: Unrelated but important: For security's sake, please specify the domains you actually use in the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` settings. Do *not* use `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`, albeit possible this is somewhat an anti-pattern. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts for the related docs.

Answer (score 1):

You may have forgotten to include the whitenoice middleware in your settings.py MIDDLEWARE setting.  Edit your settings.py file and add WhiteNoise to the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES list, above all other middleware apart from Django’s SecurityMiddleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
# 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
#...
]
```

More information can be found in the whitenoise docs: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

Go through the step-by-step setup to see what you're missing.  The Heroku docs tend to omit the middleware addition--which causes the bug--and perhaps there's something else missing for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Those staticfile settings came directly from the Heroku website (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets). When I ran `python manage.py collectstatic` I got a key error 'DATABASE_URL' which I had to `export` a value for and then when I pushed my files to Heroku the website worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the exact same problem but it's not the staticfiles its `DEBUG = False` that's causing the issue. When I realised it I remembered I visited a github repo yesterday that had the solution to my problem.

https://github.com/8sagh8/DjangoRestApi-part1-youtube-project/blob/main/README.md

You could keep changing `DEBUG` to `False` or `True` between production and development or you could use the code below

```
import sys

if (len(sys.argv) >= 2 and sys.argv[1] == 'runserver'):
   DEBUG = True
else:
   DEBUG = False
```

If you've worked with C programs this would look quite familiar, the code above   checks if you typed in `runserver` at the end of `python manage.py runserver` and sets `DEBUG` to `True` but else it will set `DEBUG` to `True`